# How do I post a Request Payload with $.post?

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$.post("http://www.roblox.com/API/Comments.ashx?rqtype=makeComment&assetID=192800", function(onWebsite) {
    body: 'hi'
});
```

If you analyze a legitimate comment request made by the client, under Request Payload in chrome, it says "hi". The body header is not doing this. How do I request payload with this script, and effectively have it shown under Request Payload?

Under Request Payload, it does not have headers, just, "hi".

Comment: The syntax is `$.post("url", {body: 'hi'}, function(response) { .. });`, but that requires that the server accepts CORS.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to put my code in that format.

Comment: Using that, it shows up under form data and body:. Is that the same thing as Request Payload? EDIT: It works, but the comment shows up as "body=test". Do I just make it {'message'}?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work thanks to adeneo who provided the correct syntax in his [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424097/how-do-i-post-a-request-payload-with-post#comment48933557_30424097):

> The syntax is `$.post("url", {body: 'hi'}, function(response) { .. });`, but that requires that the server accepts CORS.